# Cannot set properties of undefined by iteration the nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a nested JSON, this is structured as follows:
[image]

As you can see the JSON is called bwaResult and in this object there are three big groups. These groups are called actBwa, fcBwa and planBwa. These groups contain years and yearlyResults(sums) which also have years. I would like to assign the values to the individual years. That means in 2020 you would have actBwa, fcBwa, planBwa and the yearlyResults values and the same for the other years.

My Code:

```
 const plMonthResults = {};
        const plMonth = resp.success ? resp.bwaResult : null; // JSON-DATA
        delete resp.success;
        if (plMonth && plMonth !== null && Object.keys(plMonth)) {
          let count = 0;
          for (const bwaType in plMonth) {
            const plMonthData = plMonth[bwaType]; // Here I get actBwa, fcBwa, planBwa
            if (count === 0) {
              for (const yearKey of Object.keys(plMonthData)) {
                plMonthResults[yearKey] = {}; // Sort by years
              }
            }
            for (const yearKeyInPlMonth in plMonthData) {
              plMonthResults[yearKeyInPlMonth][bwaType] = plMonthData[yearKeyInPlMonth]; // Here then arises the error
            }
            count += 1;
          }
        }
```

When I run the code then I get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'fcBwa')
```

I guess since actBwa only has 2020 and the other groups have more years there is a problem finding fcBwa and iterating further or am I seeing this wrong? Can you tell me how to solve this problem?

UPDATE my work in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-local-json-file-service-udqvck?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: It's be much easier to answer your question if you provided a reproducible example.

Comment: I will now create an example in StackBlitz, where you can track the output via console.log...

Comment: i have mapped the case in StackBlitz. Would be nice if you could help me. Please look at the output in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're using `count` to copy the keys only once, but that means you will only have the keys of the first object (in this case `actBwa`). You can instead go through the key of each object, but make sure you don't override the existing ones. So remove the `count` and modify the look like this

```
       for (const yearKey of Object.keys(plMonthData)) {
          plMonthResults[yearKey] = plMonthResults[yearKey] ?? {};
        }
```

You can even remove this loop and include the check into the main one:

```
   for (const yearKeyInPlMonth in plMonthData) {
          plMonthResults[yearKeyInPlMonth] = plMonthResults[yearKeyInPlMonth] ?? {};
          plMonthResults[yearKeyInPlMonth][bwaType] = plMonthData[yearKeyInPlMonth]; 
        }
```

Let me know if that gives you the result you're after

Comment: Works. It can be as simple as that.